# Callback in LLM chain doesn't get executed

Tags: python, langchain, google-cloud-vertex-ai, py-langchain

The following code do not do what it is supposed to do:

```py
from langchain.callbacks.base import BaseCallbackHandler
from langchain import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.llms import VertexAI


class MyCustomHandler(BaseCallbackHandler):
    def on_llm_end(self, event, context):
        print(f"Prompt: {event.prompt}")
        print(f"Response: {event.response}")


llm = VertexAI(
            model_name='text-bison@001',
            max_output_tokens=1024,
            temperature=0.3,
            verbose=False)
prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template("1 + {number} = ")
handler = MyCustomHandler()
chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt, callbacks=[handler])
response = chain.run(number=2)
print(response)
```

Based on [this](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/callbacks/custom_callbacks) documentation and [this](https://www.perplexity.ai/search/c1ea9c07-baf5-4fb9-9a62-3353d68f6078?s=mn) tutorial, the code should execute the custom handler callback `on_llm_end` but in fact it doesn't.
Can anyone please tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and found the solution.

You need to pass `callback` parameter to `llm` itself. In your case you need to change the code as below

```
callback_handler  = MyCustomHandler()
llm = VertexAI(
               model_name='text-bison@001',
               max_output_tokens=1024,
               temperature=0.3,
               callbacks=[callback_handler]
               verbose=False)
```

Secondly change the implementation of `on_llm_end` as below

```
class MyCustomHandler(BaseCallbackHandler):
    def on_llm_end(self, response, **kwargs):
        print(f"Response: {response}")
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: is there a way to log the prompt as well and not just the response?

Comment: Of course, you can use `on_llm_start` method in the call back to get prompts.

ref: https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/callbacks/

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as below

```
        from langchain.callbacks import LLMonitorCallbackHandler
        from langchain.monitor import LLMonitor
        from langchain import PromptTemplate
        from langchain.chains import LLMChain
        from langchain.llms import VertexAI

        class MyCustomHandler(LLMonitorCallbackHandler):
            def on_llm_end(self, response, **kwargs):
                modified_response = response.upper()
                print(modified_response)
                return modified_response

        llm = VertexAI(
                    model_name='text-bison@001',
                    max_output_tokens=1024,
                    temperature=0.3,
                    verbose=False)
        prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template("1 + {number} = ")
        callback_handler  = MyCustomHandler()
        chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt, callbacks=[callback_handler])
        response = chain.run(number=2)
        print(response)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'MyCustomHandler' object has no attribute '_LLMonitorCallbackHandler__llmonitor_version'. Did you mean: '_LLMonitorCallbackHandler__has_valid_config'?`. My langchain version is `langchain-0.0.331`. Furthermore, I am more interested into logging the prompt sent to the LLM rather than the response. Can I get the "request" on `on_llm_end` method as well?

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct. you are probably getting errors while openai sending the response. in case of error there is `on_llm_error` which runs when LLM errors. override it on your handler class:

```
class MyCustomHandler(BaseCallbackHandler):
    def on_llm_end(self, event, context):
        print(f"Prompt: {event.prompt}")
        print(f"Response: {event.response}")
    def on_llm_error(self,error,**kwargs):
        print(f"error occured: {error}")
```

if error is printing out that is the reason `on_llm_end` is not calling

Comment: nope, no difference. There is no error. it just return the answer without ever executing any callback or returning any error.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it I found is to pass the handler to the chain `run` or `predict_and_parse` method as follows:

```
callbacks = []
logfile = "my_log_file.txt"
callbacks.append(FileCallbackHandler(logfile, mode="w"))

response = chain.predict_and_parse(callbacks=callbacks)
```